# Fixed Sized Bucket - Nested JSON Array

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have stream of events coming from a particular user. I am using Cosmos DB to store my User profile. Take following example JSON object. Here I just want to store limited set of events, say only 2. As soon as the 3rd event comes in I want to remove older one and add that 3rd event, not exceeding my bucket size. Easy way is for each update I pull the record for that User, and modify and update. Was wondering if there is any other efficient way to achieve the same.

```
{
   "id":"4717cd3c-78d9-4a0e-bf5d-4645c97bd55c",
   "email":"abc@acme.org",
   "events":[
      {
         "event":"USER_INSTALL",
         "time":1641232180,
         "data":{
            "app":"com.abc"
         }
      },
      {
         "time":1641232181,
         "event":"USER_POST_INSTALL",
         "data":{
            "app":"com.xyz"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no options to limit an array size, within a document. You would need to modify this on your own, as you're currently doing. Even if you stored each array item as a separate document, you would still need to periodically purge older documents on your own. At least, with independent documents per event, you could consider purging older events via `ttl`, but you still wouldn't be able to specify an exact number of documents to keep.